# Can I detect network and netmask of the configured connected device with static IP

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, ping, ifconfig

I am running Linux device with wired network interface. Another end of this interface is plugged into another network-aware device that is configured to use some static IP address and some netmask. Hence we have a very simple network consisting of the two devices and one cable only, not even switches between them, nothing.

The task is to start talking with that another device, and we need

1. Put the network up with ifconfig or the like.
2. Get IP address and launch  my program that uses this IP address to work with the
   device.

I know I can do the broadcast ping and obtain the IP address of the device on another end of the cable. This works for me. But to activate the network and do broadcast ping I need to know the network address and netmask. My current bash script looks like

```
ifconfig 192.168.100.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
ping -b 192.168.100.255
```

And the device responds. Unfortunately, some of these devices might be misconfigured with unpredictable network and netmask. Could anyone propose an idea how to retrieve the network settings (netbase, netmask) automatically? Would be thankful even for a partial solution. A custom C tool could be compiled and installed on my side, if this would help.

Comment: Is DHCP usable?  That's the right way to handle dynamic assignment of IP settings.  Since you're willing to compile and install a custom solution, I'd look into installing DHCP.

Comment: Does the device respond to an ICMP netmask request?

Comment: The device on another end is configured to use static IP addres and would not use DHCP even if we provide this service

Comment: "Does the device respond to an ICMP netmask request?" who knows it, could you tell me how to test? It is also Linux machine.

Comment: Ah, then it probably doesn't. SO you want to connect this device directly to your machine and discover its network configuration? Do you know if it will be in a certain range, such as 192.168.0.0?

Comment: Even if the other device isn't using DHCP, could there be a DHCP server on the network? How do all the other machines on the network get their configs? DHCP is really the only good mechanism for machines to get their IP configuration automatically.

Comment: What exactly do you know about the device? a MAC address? a possible range of (misconfigured) addresses?

Comment: These machines are mostly configured to use 192.168.*.*. A different values for netmask have been used in the past (255.225.0.0, 255.255.254.0, 255.255.255.0, I may not know all of them).

Comment: My device is Android device. Sadly, DHCP server for Android seems not exactly mature, no code at all at http://code.google.com/p/rogued/. All that remains is to build some known C-based DHCP daemon. May be possible but could it be some better solution? And, there are no any other devices on the network. We have the two connected devices and half meter of the cable, that's all.

Comment: Use link-local IPv4 addresses.  This will provide connectivity for the link, but the addresses applied to each interface will not be globally routable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part you can use nmap as long as you can somehow limit the range, as per your comment this already should give you the host you want:

```
sudo nmap -PR -sn 192.168.0-255.0-255 -e <interface-to-test>
```

This does discovery based on ARP and if succesful an additional ICMP ping for aliveness afterwards. This one took me about a second on a range with no active local hosts and 5s with 4 active hosts. So you can even expand it to a bit larger range, but not the full IPv4 address space unless you have a day or two. In that case I'd just hook up wireshark or tcpdump and wait for a gratuitous ARP.

**edit**: For this to work you have to configure your "source machine" with an IP in the subnet you want to test. I assumed it would use the DAD mode of ARP when going out of the subnet or when no ip is configured, but it just doesn't do anything. I added a more generic version to a script I wrote for the algorithm below, but it is a bit slower than simply using nmap to get this result.

Detecting the configured netmask is a bit trickier. But I think this procedure would work, the main idea is that a host will send out an ARP request for hosts in its subnet and nothing or an ARP request for its default-gw for hosts not in its subnet.

1. Start with the second to smallest subnet `N=29`.
2. Pick an IP `X` from this subnet formed by the host's IP and the subnet mask `N`. Make sure the picked IP is not the host's IP and not network/broadcast. Also make sure this IP is not a part of the subnet formed by the host's IP and mask `N+1`.
3. Ping the other host with source `X` (you don't care if it answers, just send out a request)
4. If you see an ARP request for `X`, decrease `N` with one. go back to 2
5. If you don't see an ARP request for `X`, `N+1` is the subnet searched.

One flaw might be that a overambitious network stack implementation might learn the MAC from the incoming ICMP request, but I personally do not know of any end-device stack that works this way.

I don't know if there are tools that do this for you, but it should be easy to do manually with ping, tcpdump and a subnet calculator ;). Or if you feel up to some hacking, it's probably not that much work to implement this with [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/)

I went along and wrote a full python scapy script myself that should work, I tested it on my home network on a linksys homegw, another linux machine and an android device:

```
from __future__ import print_function, absolute_import, unicode_literals
from scapy.base_classes import Net
from scapy.config import conf
from scapy.layers.inet import Ether, ARP, ICMP, IP
from scapy.sendrecv import srp, debug
import scapy.route

iface = b'eth0'
subnet_to_test = b'192.168.1.0/24'
#or:
subnet_to_test = b'192.168.1.*'

#IP/MAC discovery
pkt = Ether(dst=b'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff') / ARP(psrc=b'0.0.0.0', pdst=subnet_to_test, hwdst=b'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff')
responses = srp(pkt, timeout=1, retry=0, verbose=0, iface=iface)
for r in responses[0]:
    found = r[1].getfieldval('psrc')
    foundmac = r[1].getfieldval('hwsrc')

n = 29
conf.debug_match = 1
while n > -1:
    net = Net("{}/{}".format(found, n))
    my_src = net.choice()
    while my_src in Net("{}/{}".format(found, n + 1)):
        my_src = net.choice()
    pkt = Ether(dst=foundmac) / IP(dst=found, src=my_src) / ICMP(type=8)
    resp = srp(pkt, timeout=1, retry=0, verbose=0, iface=iface, filter=b'ether dst FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF and arp')
    received = [x for x in debug.recv if x.haslayer(ARP) and x.getfieldval('pdst') == my_src]
    received.extend(x[1] for x in resp[0] if x[1].haslayer(ARP) and x[1].getfieldval('pdst') == my_src)
    if len(received) == 0:
        print("Found host: {}/{} on mac {}".format(found, n + 1, foundmac))
        break
    n -= 1
```

Comment: nmap will not work when the interface has no IP address on it yet.  Also, your algorithm for mask detection does not work.  It will return the largest mask for which you are able to allocate an address, but this does not mean that you have the same mask as the neighbouring device.

Comment: @ will c. The whole point is that there is a configured but unknown address. And my algorithm has nothing to do with allocation :S, its only flaw is that the target host might learn the Mac from the incoming icmp and doesn't ARP at all, but in that case you just need to change the trigger to detect packets to another ip (I.e. default gw).

Comment: There is a configured but unknown address on the *target* machine, but there is no IP address on the *source* machine.  Without an IP address on the source machine, there is no way you can use nmap on it, all the ARP replies will be dropped on the target machines.  When I say allocation, I just mean taking an IP address from the block and putting it on the source interface.

Comment: @WillC. you're right, I assumed nmap would fall back to DAD when forcing PR outside of your subnet but it doesn't, I'll update with a script of my own. The algorithm does work by the way, I implemented and verified it a bit here.

Comment: I still don't get your point about my algorithm though. Allocation is just one part (which I included), the actual important thing is to check the target host's ARP behaviour. A host will ARP for something in its subnet and will not ARP or will ARP for it's default-gw for something that is not in its subnet.

Comment: The algorithm won't work if there are multiple subnets within the same collision domain.  This is not a plausible scenario for the poster, so I accept your solution.

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking for is not possible.

Initially, you have an interface with no IP address on it.  Because of this, any packets you send out will not know where to send the replies (ICMP, or ARP request will therefore not work).

Since senders' don't know how to reach this interface, you could listen on the interface for any broadcast ARP requests (using tcpdump, wireshark, etc.)  This will show you what IP addresses are being resolved in the network, but it does not give you the net mask (and hence the network address).  Furthermore, it does not *only* provide you with the directly connected neighbour's IP address, it will give you *all* of the ARP requests made within this broadcast domain (so you will possibly see many IP addresses).

Now, as for determining the network mask that the device is using, it is not possible when CIDR is employed (the prefix could be anywhere between /16 and /32, and there is no way to know exactly which one the neighbour device is using.)

That being said, you may want to look into link-local IPv4 addresses.  On Linux, there is a program called AVAHI, and on Windows it is called APIPA.  Both implement RFC 3927: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927

Link-local addresses can only be used to communicate with devices on the same physical or logical link, so if you actually want this device to be on the same subnet, you will have to manually configure the interface.

Comment: The test machine is under his control, he can always configure it with some address. But ARP can be done without a configured address (DAD mode), even more, it's a recommended step to do *before* you actually apply an address. There are no other devices and possible other ip's, the question clearly states it's a point-to-point link. I provided an algorithm in my answer how to detect the netmask which works fine (tested).

Comment: Agreed, I was thinking of this problem in a much broader sense (multiple devices, multiple subnets, sharing the same collision domain).  I still think using link-local addresses is a much simpler approach to solving this problem though.